# Android SQLite retrieving data from the database and displaying that data in text

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a working SQlite database in my application. I can add new values to the database. I have even created a method which displays all the results of the table on a new activity.

What I would this new activity really to do, is to display *the most recent entry* into text views. Picking individual fields and slotting them into correct text views. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using autogenerated ID in your table, you need to sort the results based on ID and limit the results to '1' which will return only that row.

```
return db.query(true, "yourTableName", new String[] { "columnNamesYouwanttoQuery" },
                null, null, null, null, "_id DESC", "1");
```

Then loop through the cursor and get yourColumns

```
Cursor cur = adaptor.getMileageReport(AutoMainActivity.CARNAME);
        startManagingCursor(cur);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do { 
String retrievedVal = cur.getString(0);
             } 
}
```